# Is TI lying or over selling their solar charging ICs?

Tags: texas-instruments, solar-charge-controller

I came across the BQ25703A IC on TI's [webiste](https://www.ti.com/power-management/battery-management/charger-ics/products.html#1152=2%3B5&%7E2192=Power%20Path%3BSolar%20input%2FMPPT&sort=2192;desc&). It clearly shows Solar input/MPPT. However, there is no mention of this in their datasheet.

So am I missing something or is TI lying and overselling this IC?

**Datasheet:**

[BQ25703A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25703a.pdf?ts=1711302833530&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fbattery-management%252Fcharger-ics%252Fproducts.html)

[image]

Comment: There are a couple of possibilities.  The Vin dpm feature can give you MPPT-like operation if you know your panel's max power point.  The other possibility is that during cut and paste of the features, whoever entered the part's features online forgot to delete the MPPT wording.  Out and out lying is not one of the possibilities.  See here:https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sluaap0/sluaap0.pdf?ts=1711224042418&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Ft.co%252F#:~:text=Using%20MPPT%20requires%20input%20voltage,to%20lower%20the%20input%20voltage.

Comment: This site is about electronics design. We do not judge IC quality except in general terms.

Comment: At the bottom of the TI [Battery charger ICs](https://www.ti.com/power-management/battery-management/charger-ics/products.html#1152=2%3B5&%7E2192=Power%20Path%3BSolar%20input%2FMPPT&sort=2192;desc&) website link from the question, these is a [Website feedback](https://www.ti.com/guidedsupport/docs/webform/tiwebsitefeedback.tsp). You could possibly submit some feedback asking if the parametric information on the website is correct.

Comment: @JohnD thank you for the link, the IC is not even in the table. Likely the ones that are they do not require to many adjustments.... Still sucks when big electronic companies cannot even get the simple things right.

Comment: @JoeyB Why would it need to be stated in the datasheet? Is it wrong to leave it out? For example, a TI 74HC595 is said to have an application in network switches, power infrastructure, LED displays and servers. Is it wrong to connect it to an Arduino then, since that's not in the list of application? Or should you explicitly list everything you possibly can use it for?

Comment: @Justme with respect, the evaluation board for the IC cost around $160. Your example IC is no way in the ball park. So YES for that MONEY, it should be stated, don't you think...?

Comment: @JoeyB Eval boards do cost a lot. That eval board is cheap. The chip does not cost a lot, only $1.38 in batches of 1000. It has cost many hours of paid engineering work to design, manufacture and test a very small batch of those eval boards with all the other components, write manuals and documentation, order the cardboard boxes and prepare the kit for you. And the eval board has no relation to what is printed on chip data sheet by marketing people. Data sheets may be old or they may be updated and the buzzword list may or may not be important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is TI lying ...

Almost definately not.

> ... or over selling their solar charging ICs?

Not likely either, though it could be an honest mistake - feel free to contact TI for clarification on this point.

> the evaluation board for the IC cost around $160

To give you wider context, this is *not* an expensive evaluation board.

---

The *feature* that is listed and you're taking objection to is "*Solar input/MPPT*", which could be read as "*Solar input **or** MPPT*" (e.g: "*Li-Ion/Li-Polymer*" as listed in the cell chemistry parameter). The BQ25703A has a nice wide input voltage range (3.5v to 24v), and supports both buck and boost modes of operation... therefore it's a very good candidate for use in low voltage solar systems.

When it comes to MPPT (i.e: [Maximum Power Point Tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking)), this is about finding the optimal balance between current and voltage... Item 5 of the first page of the datasheet is "*Input Current and Voltage Regulation*", with "*±2% Input/Charge Current Regulation*" and "*±5% Power Monitor*" listed further down.
It even says "*Input Current Optimizer (ICO) to Extract Max Input Power*"!

This part also has `ACP` and `ACN` pins to sense the input current, along with `SRP` and `SRN` for the battery current as shown on the first page of the datasheet, and it looks like this is available as a buffered analog signal (see `IADPT` and `IBAT`), or via I2C too.

[image: application diagram, with the current sense resistor circled]

I'm not going to sit here and fully understand the part for you, but a quick skim through shows that the charge current can be regulated to a resolution of 64mA (64mA through to 8.128 A - see Section 8.6.3)...

All of this just reinforces the potential for using this part in a system that  implements MPPT... it equips you for the job, have at it!

You'll often find that buzz-words and acronyms like "*MPPT*" are useful for the high-level summary view, but when you get into the deeper technical details, other words and phrases start to take their place. Don't forget, that the list of features presented on the website will be produced by very different people to the technical content in datasheets.